# Should we merge to a single tag for web3.js?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I tried creating tag synonyms https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms.  Saw on some meta SE that they just aren't used much.

Should we merge [web3js](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web3js) [web3.js](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web3.js) [web3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web3) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [web3.js](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web3.js) and [web3js](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web3js) are the same and refer both to the [web3 javascript api](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/).

<del>No, [web3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web3) is a general term referring to [the *web 3.0*](https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/08/18/building-decentralized-web/). I have mixed feelings about this. It might be too broad. It could either be removed or renamed to [web-three](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-three) to distinguish the difference to wbe3.js. But that again could be confused with the recently rebranded C++ project [webthree](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree).</del> Right, let's do it.

Comment: Current questions in [tag:web3] aren't about the decentralized web and I'm not sure about reserving it for that purpose.  For c++ webthree, fortunately those questions do seem to be tagged correctly with [tag:cpp-ethereum].  If it becomes needed maybe they can be new tag [tag:web3cpp]

Comment: web3 is also used by geth, and I suspect the APIs might diverge slightly between web3 in geth and web3.js.  But I"m all for merging web3.js and web3js, I'm  just double tagging as it is...